# Can not boot Boot-Repair live cd

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, kernel, windows, boot-repair

I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 and windows 8.1. I can boot both O.S using the BIOS boot options (manually).
I want to select O.S from a grub screen when PC starts. So i tried to use a boot repair live CD to repair grub/boot. The problem is when I select "64-bit session" in the boot repair menu an error appears:

> kernel panic at boot: not syncing. No init found

Pastebin: http://paste.ubuntu.com/15368305/

Answer (score 0):

As per your boot-repair report(translated to English)

```
The boot files [ Linux ] are far from the beginning of the disc . Your BIOS could not detect them . You may want to retry after creating a partition / boot ( EXT4 , > 200MB , beginning of the disc ) . This can be done with tools like GParted . Then select this partition through the [ separate / boot partition ] of [Boot Repair ] . ( Https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootPartition )

If your computer boots directly into Windows , try changing the boot order in the BIOS.
If your BIOS does not support changing the boot order , change the default entry in the Windows boot loader .
For example you can start Windows , then type the following command in a cmd window with administrator privileges :
bcdedit / set { bootmgr } path \ EFI \ ... \ grub * .EFI
```

I won't take the first point very seriously...but the second one is worth trying

***For example you can start Windows , then type the following command in a cmd window with administrator privileges :***

```
bcdedit / set { bootmgr } path \ EFI \ ... \ grub * .EFI
```

Give this a try.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could give it a try with Super GRUB 2 disk.

You can download it from [here](http://www.supergrubdisk.org/).

Then install it in a usb using [Unetbootin](http://sourceforge.net/projects/unetbootin/)
Now you could restart your system and make sure it is set in the boot option menu.

Comment: I tried with Super grub2. When I select "Detect any OS" it shows me only Linux options